# How to merge data from multiple dicts into a single row in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I want to merge a few dictionaries with the same keys together without deleting any key / value pairs and convert to a `DataFrame`.

I have tried `dict.update()`, but it replaces former values with new ones for duplicate keys.

```
dict3[1]
{'DB': 'M',
 'TITLE': 'ACM Journal of Computer Documentation ',
 'ISSN': '1527-6805',
 'e-ISSN': '1557-9441',
 'ISBN': nan,
 'e-ISBN': nan}

dict4[0]
{'DB': 'D',
 'TITLE': 'ACM Computing Surveys ',
 'ISSN': '0360-0300',
 'e-ISSN': '1557-7341',
 'ISBN': nan,
 'e-ISBN': nan}
```

I would like the result to keep all the keys in the same row no matter if the values are same or different although they are overlapping keys.
The table should look as follows:

```
   DB      TITLE         ISSN      e-ISSN  ...    DB     TITLE        ISSN ...
0   M   ACM Journal... 1527-6805  1557-9441  ...   D  ACM Comput... 0360-0300...
```

Comment: Your desired dict has multiple instances of the same keys. Python can't do that.

Comment: As noted by @glibdud, python dicts require unique keys. Why do you want a collection of key value pairs where the keys are not unique (what are you trying to accomplish)? Depending on what you are really trying to do, [`collections.ChainMap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#chainmap-objects) might be useful.

Comment: @benvc, I wanted to group them together so when i transfer them into a dataframe, they will show as a whole row.

Comment: Then you should edit your question and ask how you could merge data from multiple dicts with the same keys into a single row in a `DataFrame` (there are more was to create a `DataFrame` than from a single dict). Be sure to include an example of the expected output from the resulting `DataFrame`.

Comment: @benvc, i have edited it into a better form. Thanks a lot ! I'm still new to programming and still learning. Thanks for your guide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could concatenate the keys of each dict to represent your row columns, and then concatenate the values of each dict into a single row (passed to the `DataFrame` constructor as a nested dict to create a row rather than a single column). For example:

```
import pandas as pd

nan = float('nan')
d1 = {'DB': 'M', 'TITLE': 'ACM Journal of Computer Documentation', 'ISSN': '1527-6805', 'e-ISSN': '1557-9441', 'ISBN': nan, 'e-ISBN': nan}
d2 = {'DB': 'D', 'TITLE': 'ACM Computing Surveys', 'ISSN': '0360-0300', 'e-ISSN': '1557-7341', 'ISBN': nan, 'e-ISBN': nan}

columns = [*d1.keys(), *d2.keys()]
row = [*d1.values(), *d2.values()]
df = pd.DataFrame([row], columns=columns)
print(df)
#   DB                                  TITLE  ...  DB                  TITLE
# 0  M  ACM Journal of Computer Documentation  ...   D  ACM Computing Surveys
```

You could create a simple function to convert an arbitrary number of dicts to a single row `DataFrame` using the same basic approach. For example:

```
def dicts_to_single_row_df(*args):
    columns = [k for d in args for k in d.keys()]
    row = [v for d in args for v in d.values()]
    return pd.DataFrame([row], columns=columns)

df = dicts_to_single_row_df(d1, d2)
```

Comment: How to make the dicts run altogether? Cause i have around 120k of dicts like this, and some needs to do so while others don't. I tried this method and implement it into a loop and i manage to get it running still for only a row, (The other rows, like d3 and d4 and d5 for the index[1] wont come out.)

Comment: @WeiLunss - are you trying to create multiple rows in the same `DataFrame` from various groups of dicts? If so, will each row have the same number of columns?

Comment: Yes, but not all rows have the same number of columns, as this work is actually about putting duplicates with different 'DB' at the back. For those who are unique, they wont have any dicts to pair up with them. These dicts shown here were actually nested dicts, which i transfrom them from a table row by row, a row is a dict itself.

Comment: My concept is to compare them one by one, when found duplicates in another dict, merge them up together as a row. So there might be a row where there is only a single dict, and rows which might have up to a few dicts paired up together.

Comment: @WeiLunss - that is quite a bit different than the current question. You are probably better off posting a separate question (because the activity on the current question will just confuse other readers given that your ultimate goal is quite different than the example here). I would suggest posting a question that shows an example of the data you are starting with (and indicates whether it is a `DataFrame`, list of dicts, or whatever it is) and then explain the conditions that will determine which rows should be concatenated and which should remain unchanged.